# Search label by first characters on GitHub

Tags: github, search

I'm on GitHub. I can search like this:

https://github.com/jenstornell/kirby-plugins/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22Type%3A+Plugin%22

The query looks like this:

```
is:issue is:open label:"Type: Plugin"
```

Now many labels contains the word `Type:` in the beginning. Can I match just the first characters to match issues that has tags like `Type: Plugin` and `Type: Core`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no wildcard search for labels on GitHub:
https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/#search-by-label

Additionally there is also unfortunately no way to combine several `label:` filters with `OR`, so if you know the list of labels you are looking for, you can not even construct a string that includes them all as this will only search for issues containing *both* labels.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you can search issues tagged with different labels:

'label:bug,resolved matches issues with the label "bug" or the label "resolved."'